# How do I append a date to a file using Bash script with multiple variables?

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

My script is below, I can't remember how to make this make sense.

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
output=$2
cp $input $output_$(date +%m%d%y)
```

The goal is to run the script as follows

```
/path/script.sh /path/file_name /path/archive/
```

Archived file would then be
`/path/archive/file_name_090718`

Comment: If you want the script to reference arguments passed to it, these would be in $1, $2, etc.  In this case $1 would be /path/file_name and $2 would be /path/archive/

Comment: That is correct, the script will have varying arguments depending on what files it is archiving and where. $1 will always be the original file and $2 will always be the new destination.

Comment: Don't be afraid to "play".  Try commenting out the `cp` line and echo the values of `${input}` and `${output}`.  Run the script with no/different arguments.  What do you see?  Add an echo to output `${output}_$(date +%m%d%y)`, what do you see?  Once you've done that, you'll be in a better position to know what `cp` command to use.

Comment: CURLY BRACKETS!! That's what I kept forgetting.

If anybody else lands on this question, the answer is curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `${output}` in `{}` brackets allows the concatenation of the underscore and date. Alternatively you could just use `cp $1 $2_$(date +%m%d%y)`.

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
output=$2
cp ${input} ${output}_$(date +%m%d%y)
```

Usage:

```
$ ls
file_name script.sh
$./script.sh file_name archive
$ ls
archive_090718 file_name script.sh
```

Comment: You would also need to double quote the variable expansions to cope with filenames containing whitespace and/or characters that the shell would otherwise treat as globbing patterns. See e.g.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters  The curly braces are only needed in the destination path where the value of the `output` variable is concatenated with an underscore.

Comment: The goal is to append the file_name while placing it in the archive. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

THE ANSWER IS CURLY BRACKETS!

This is how I did it; it's not the prettiest way to skin a cat...

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
output=$2
cp $input ${output}_$(date +%m%d%y)
```

```
$ ./script /usr/tmp/file_name /usr/tmp/arch/file_name
```

```
$ ls -l /usr/tmp/arch
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxxxx yyyyyyy 5 Sep  7 12:06 file_name_090718
```